# Add array values to hidden form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to add comma separated values to a hidden form field for later processing using the change of a dropdown menu as my trigger.

```js
$("#artistselect").change(function() {
  var allids = [];

  allids.push($(this).children(":selected").attr("id"));

  $("input[name=artistslist]").attr("value", $(allids).append(allids + ", "));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="artistselect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="artistslist" value="" />
</form>
```

Best I can manage is to get the value to change to the selected dropdown, but it wont add them together with the commas.

Comment: What is the purpose of `allids.push($(this).children(":selected").attr("id"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `var allids=[];` out of the event because you're destroying it every time it fires.

```
var allids=[];

$("#artistselect").change(function() {
    allids.push($(this).children(":selected").attr("id"));

     $("input[name=artistslist]").val(allids.join(', '));
});
```

On the last line you can use [Array.prototype.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to get a comma separated string from the array.

Not sure why you are using `.attr("id")` when your html shows your options with no id attribute. Looks like you want value not id.

Comment: This sort of works, except I am getting <input type="hidden" name="artistslist" id="artistlistecho" value="13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15"> in my hidden field...

Comment: nevermind, I derped, the javasript was inside a php while loop. your code works perfectly. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

First, you're emptying `allids` every time the user selects from the menu. So when you push onto it, you lose the old values, and you just get the most recent value.

Second, `$(allids).append(allids + ", ")` doesn't do what you think it does. `.append()` is for adding something to a DOM element, not concatenating strings.

To get the value of a `<select>`, just use `$(this).val()`, you don't need to search for `:selected`. Your `<option>` elements don't have IDs, so `.attr('id')` won't return anything.

```js
var allids = [];
$("#artistselect").change(function() {
  allids.push($(this).val());
  $("input[name=artistslist]").val(allids.join(", "));
});

$("#show").click(function() {
    console.log($("input[name=artistslist]").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="artistselect">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="artistslist" value="" />
  <button type="button" id="show">Show hidden value</button>
</form>
```